SELINUX: Failed to resolve typeattributeset statement at /var/lib/selinux/mls/tmp/modules/400/base_container/cil:6
Try to run generated by udica selinux policy
(block c4
(blockinherit container)
(blockinherit restricted_net_container)
(allow process process ( capability ( chown dac_override fowner fsetid kill net_bind_service setfcap setgid setpcap setuid sys_chroot ))) 

(allow process http_port_t ( tcp_socket (  name_bind ))) 
(allow process container_file_t ( dir ( add_name create getattr ioctl lock open read remove_name rmdir search setattr write ))) 
(allow process container_file_t ( file ( append create getattr ioctl lock map open read rename setattr unlink write ))) 
(allow process container_file_t ( fifo_file ( getattr read write append ioctl lock open ))) 
(allow process container_file_t ( sock_file ( append getattr open read write ))) 
(allow process user_home_t ( dir ( add_name create getattr ioctl lock open read remove_name rmdir search setattr write ))) 
(allow process user_home_t ( file ( append create getattr ioctl lock map open read rename setattr unlink write ))) 
(allow process user_home_t ( fifo_file ( getattr read write append ioctl lock open ))) 
(allow process user_home_t ( sock_file ( append getattr open read write ))) 
)

Apply:
semodule -i c4.cil /usr/share/udica/templates/{base_container.cil,net_container.cil}

Got an error:
Failed to resolve typeattributeset statement at 

Failed to resolve typeattributeset statement at /var/lib/selinux/mls/tmp/modules/400/base_container/cil:6
Failed to resolve AST
semodule:  Failed!

What does this error mean and how to fix i

It looks like in /var/lib/selinux/mls/tmp/modules/400/base_container/cil, line 6, there is a non-existing type. Can you please comment with what is written on line 6?
